# llamar una funcion javascript en php (para luego hacer una consulta en el php )

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

> Parte superior: consulta previa de los datos

```php
<?php
  function conexion(){
    $conn = null;
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'mi_base_datos';
    $user = 'usuario';
    $pwd = '';

    try{
      $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.'; dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      exit();
    }
    return $conn;
  }

  $cn = conexion();
  $sql= "select idMateriaPrima as id, nombre as name from materiaprima where estado = 1";
  $query = $cn->query($sql);
  $datos = $query->fetchAll();

?>
```

> Parte intermedia: uso de los datos calculados, incrustados como JSON en el HTML

```js
var variableJS = document.getElementById('datoHaObtener').value;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-init='friends = <?php echo json_encode($datos); ?>'></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="banco" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Producto</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input id="datoHaObtener" list="searchTextResults"  class="form-control" ng-model="searchText" required>
      <datalist id="searchTextResults">
        <option  ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText" value="{{friend.name}}"></option>
      </datalist>
      
      <br>
      
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="banco" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Precio</label>
      <select required class="form-control" name="precixd" id="precixd">
        <option  value="0">Seleccione</option>
      </select>
      <label for="banco" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Precio</label>
      <input  id="helloo" type="text" name="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Parte final: Lo que deseo realizar

```
<?php

    $ConsultaDato = "(aqui quiero el dato que me debe pasar el javascript)";
    $conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sistemahierroforjado");

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT precioUnitario FROM materiaprima where nombre = '$ConsultaDato' ");
    while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
    {
        $respuesta = $consulta['precioUnitario'];
    }
    echo "$respuesta";
 ?>
```

Comment: <script>var num =document.getElementById('ObtieneDatoImput').value;</script>// me obtine lo del impul que esta seleccionado
<?php

 $jxj = ('aqui quiero la variable de javascript');
    $conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sistemahierroforjado");

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT precioUnitario FROM materiaprima where nombre = '$jxj' ");
      while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
      {
        $respuesta = $consulta['precioUnitario'];
      }
      echo "$respuesta";
 ?>

Comment: Alvin mejor edita la pregunta en vez de añadir el código en el comentario

Comment: ¿Llamar una función `javascript` en `PHP`? ¿O transmitir por `javascript` el resultado de una función a `PHP`?

Comment: Explica mejor eso de "llamar una funcion javascript en php". No entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente.

Comment: Baya tengo un input en donde elijo un nombre ese mismo quiero que se haga una consulta mysql en donde quiero pasarle ese dato como un where  y la funcion de script que tengo ahi me coge por medio del id del input el dato y ese es el que com php quiero compararlo

Comment: He editado tu pregunta, para que así seccionada por trozos sea mas fácil de comprender. Sin embargo no es suficiente que solo incrustes código sin expresar textualmente que es lo que solicitas, ni en que parte se acumula tu duda, Recuerda que la comunidad esta para colaborar pero no es su tarea tratar de descifrar lo que los OP quieren expresar, debes ser claro y preciso.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba algo como esto:

```
<script>
  var num =document.getElementById('ObtieneDatoImput').value;

  jQuery.get("prueba.php", {numero:num})
    .then(function (response) {
      document.getElementById("resultado").value = response;
    }
  );
</script>
```

Con jQuery.get se hace la petición al servidor, al fichero llamado prueba.php, y se le pasa el dato {numero: num}, que en php recibirá un array, con clave numero, y valor del numero que habías obtenido. (Tendrás que tener jQuery activo para este caso)

Y luego el resultado del fichero es lo que llegará al response de la funcion js.

```
// me obtine lo del impul que esta seleccionado
<?php
    $jxj = $_GET['numero'];
    $conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sistemahierroforjado");

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT precioUnitario FROM materiaprima where nombre = '$jxj' ");
      while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
      {
        $respuesta = $consulta['precioUnitario'];
      }
      echo $respuesta;
?>

<script>
```

Espero te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Las pregunta que no tienen mucha coherencia o datos minimos para ser respondidas no deberían responderse.

Comment: soso para ty talvez no!!

Comment: Antes tenía algo más de contenido, no se porque la editó así. xD

Comment: a esque ese es el ejemplo completo ahi esta todo como es en verdad la parte que estaba antes era solamente lo que queria modoficar pero ahori esta todo solo que como hago uso de Angular

Comment: A lo que se refiere el compañero, es que tienes que ser más explicito, ahora has puesto todo el código (que esta muy bien) pero no hay ninguna descripción de cual es el problema/duda/error por lo que necesites ayuda.

Comment: si es cierto baya esque no hayo la forma de como obtener lo que hay en el input para luego consultarlo mysql  en php

Comment: El input esta en un form? si es así con la propia validación del form la tendrías en el servidor y podrías tratarlo con php normal. Si no prueba como te he dicho, con ajax.

Comment: si asi lo are con ajax